# Give an example of $X,Y$ and $A$ and a continuous function $f:A \rightarrow Y$ for which there is no continuous extension to $\overline{A}$

Tags: normed-spaces

Give an example of $X,Y$ and $A$ and a continuous function $f:A \rightarrow Y$ for which there is no continuous extension to $\overline{A}$.

$X$ and $Y$ are normed spaces and $\overline{A}$ is the smallest closed subset of $X$ which contains $A$.

I don't have any particular answers to this.

Comment: $f(u)(x) = u'(x)$, $X = L_p([0;1])$, $Y = L_q([0;1])$

Answer (score 3):

$f:(0,1]\rightarrow R, f(x)=1/x$.

Comment: Could you please explain why it works?

Comment: You can extend $1/x$ at $0$ since the limit $lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}1/x=+\infty$

Comment: can't* ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: $\overline(A)$ is the intersection of all closed sets in X containing A ( I should have mentioned this at the top sorry). Does your example still hold?